# Geometrical problem of maximum area of smallest triangle formed by 3 points in a distribution of n points on an R^2 plane

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Another way of stating the gist of the question is: find the arrangement of n points such that one obtains the largest ratio between the area of the smallest triangle formed by three points to the area  bounded by lines at the edge of the figure drawn by connecting all points in a plane. Points may not be collinear. Or if they are, this would not give the optimal solution since area = 0.

Something tells me that the optimal solution is always a distribution of points equidistant along the circumference of a circle, but I don't have the ability to prove it. Got any suggestions? Thanks guys.

Comment: That first sentence over three lines is a real pain. Try splitting that up, perhaps intzroduce a bit of math notation. Is your denominator the area of the convex hull of the point set?